# How to get only page path in expres.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url

How can i get **only** page path in express.js?
I want to render a page based on url.Like if i try to access `http://example.com/a_lion` My code will search for a object which title matches with the path(a_lion) in an array,If it exist then it will render my `stories.ejs` file with data it found in the object.If not it will render the same page with "not found" data.
Here is my `index.js` file code snippet:

```
app.get("*",(req,res) => {
  
  if(req.url == "/"){
      res.render("index",{title:"Recent Stories"});
  }else{
    console.log(req.path);
   fs.readFile("stories.json",(err,data) => {
     
     if(err){throw err}
     else{
      
      let actualData = JSON.parse(data.toString());
      let mainData = actualData.find((e) => {
       return e.title === req.url;
      })
      
      if(mainData == undefined){
         res.render("stories",{title:"Ops,",body:"Not found!"});
      }else{
        res.render("stories",{title:mainData.title,body:mainData.body})
      }
     }
     
   });
   
  } 
})
```

In the `console.log(req.path);` line it outputs some urls like this:

```
/a_lion
/favicon.ico
```

I just want the `/a_lion` line not the other so my code can search it in the array.How can i achieve this?

Comment: You asked to handle *all* requests with `*`. If there are some (like the favicon, or other assets) you don't want to handle, either check for them conditionally in the handler you have now, or add an earlier static handler to serve them.

Comment: You get two log lines because you handle two requests. Those are __not__ printed from a single `req.path`.

Comment: You should consider using a better path than `"*"`. For instance if you use `/story/:name` and link to `/story/a_lion` then `req.params.name` will be `a_lion`.

Comment: @Chris G hmmm, Yes I should do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking. You can't.

The client asks for something. The server gets the request for that thing and has to determine what it is.

Most browsers will, when loading a page from a new website, ask for a favicon to display in (for example) the tab. This is normal behaviour.

There's no real way to distinguish between a browser asking for an image and one asking for an HTML document.

Some browsers *might* send different `Accept` headers depending on what they are asking for, but I wouldn't depend on that.

---

Automatically requested resources (like `favicon.ico` and `robots.txt`) tend to be top-level resources.

Make use of paths to have a more specific convention for your resources rather than chucking everything at the top level where you can't distinguish one thing from another.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Recent Stories'});
});

app.get('/stories/:title', (req, res) => {
    // ...
    const match = actualData.find((e) => e.title === req.params.title)
    // etc
});
```

---

If you're going to send a "Ops" pages with a "Not found" message then just make it a 404 error and be done with it. Browsers know what to do if they ask for a `favicon.ico` and get a 404 error … even if it is a nicely formatted 404 error.

Answer (score -1):

***Updated***

I would recommend you to split your handler and then add specific pages loading logic.

Additionally, if your `stories.json` file does not change, you can avoid reading/parsing it on every request. (Further logic can be implemented to update it in memory when needed though).

```js
const stories = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('stories.json', 'utf8')).reduce((acc, val) => {
    acc[val.title] = val.body;
    return acc;
}, {});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {title: 'Recent Stories'});
});

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    const story = stories[req.url];

    if (story) {
        res.render('stories', {title: req.url, body: story});
    } else {
        res.render('stories', {title: 'Ops,', body: 'Not found!'});
    }
});
```

Comment: The entire point of OP's approach is to *not* have to spell out potentially dozens of routes.

Comment: @ChrisG sorry, I misinterpreted the question. Just fixed my answer.